# hyperref: pdfpagelayout={TwoPageRight} doesn't work in a document starting with even-numbered page

Tags: hyperref, pdf, acrobat

According to the hyperref documentation, setting pdfpagelayout to "TwoPageRight" (or to "TwoColumnRight") should lead to displaying two pages/columns, odd-numbered pages to the right. However:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfpagelayout={TwoPageRight},
}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

If you open the resulting document in Acrobat, even pages appear on right. Is it possible to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the [documentation](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) for `TwoColumnRight` clearly says, "Display the pages in two columns, with odd numbered pages on the right," Acrobat seems to treat this as meaning display the first page on the right. Here's an example with three even numbered pages. It's displayed right, left, right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfminorversion=7
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pdfpagelayout=TwoColumnRight]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{4}
\lipsum[2]
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{6}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

My best guess is that `TwoPageRight` (which didn't work for me regardless) and `TwoColumnRight` (which did) do not consider logical page numbers. So if you start with an even numbered page, you should use `TwoPageLeft` or `TwoColumnLeft` instead.

(For what it's worth, although later versions of the PDF specification claim `TwoPageRight` and `TwoPageLeft` appear in PDF version 1.5, the v1.5 [spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference15_v5.pdf) doesn't list them. I tried changing the `\pdfminorversion` but that had no apparent effect.)

Comment: TH., thank you for the answer and analysis. That's exactly what I was afraid of -- that Acrobat takes into account physical pages only. And that's really pointless behaviour, because, as you said, "TwoColumnRight" effectively means "display the first (not odd) page on the right". Thankfully, \hypersetup{} for this parameter can be done mid-document.

Comment: I seem to remember that there's a switch for Acrobat on which pages double-side page spreads start. But who uses Acrobat anymore? :-)

Comment: Me not, but unfortunately, the most of the people supposed to use my PDFs do use Acrobat... :( One day, I noticed that my beautifully prepared articles open in Acrobat with first (odd) page to the left! I was shocked, but it seems that Acrobat is so dull that the default behaviour (without any hyperref settings) is to simply and blatantly open the first page to the left. While finding a solution, I encountered the problem I posted here... (No to speak that there's no way to tell Acrobat: "open in single page view, put please open odd pages to the right if a user switch to double page view"...)